# ts(6385) subscribe deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm getting a error message for subscribe to be deprecated.
The first is my API service
but the issue lays in the second part of the code for the function getStarwarsHeroes. The .subscribe is crossed through and i get the deprecated error.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

export interface ApiResult {
  page: number;
  results: any[];
  total_pages: number;
  total_results: number;
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getStarwarsHeroes(page:number =1): Observable <ApiResult> {
      return this.http.get<ApiResult>(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${page}/`);
    }

    getStarwarsDetails(id:string): Observable<any>{
      return this.http.get<ApiResult>(
        `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${id}/`
      );
    }

  }
```

My page where I want to display the star wars characters:
First the TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService} from '../api.service';
import { InfiniteScrollCustomEvent, LoadingController} from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit { 

  starwars:any=[];
  currentPage:number= 1;

  constructor(
    private apiService:ApiService,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.loadStarwars();  
  }
    
  async loadStarwars(event?: InfiniteScrollCustomEvent) {
    const loading= await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Loading..',
      spinner: 'bubbles',
    });
    await loading.present();
    
    this.apiService.getStarwarsHeroes(this.currentPage).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        loading.dismiss();
        this.starwars.push(...res.results);

 console.log(this.starwars);

        event?.target.complete();
        if (event) {
          event.target.disabled = res.total_pages === this.currentPage;
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        loading.dismiss();
      }
    );
  }

  loadMore(event: InfiniteScrollCustomEvent) {
      this.currentPage++;
      this.loadStarwars(event);
    }
}
```

Then the HTML file:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      StarWars Characters
    </ion-title>
    <ion-button slot="start">
    <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

 <ion-card 
 *ngFor='let item of starwars'
 [routerLink]="[item.id]"
 >
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title slot="start">{{item.name}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content slot="end">{{item.gender}}    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing in a next function and an error function, pass in an object with a next function and an error function as properties on the object.

```
subscribe({
  next: (res) => {
    loading.dismiss();
    this.starwars.push(...res.results);

    console.log(this.starwars);

    event?.target.complete();
    if (event) {
      event.target.disabled = res.total_pages === this.currentPage;
    }
  },
  error: (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    loading.dismiss();
  }
})
```

The deprecated message is because this is now the preferred method of passing in multiple functions, you can still pass in a single next function if you don't need the other functions.